# How to ignore the last five lines of a CSV file While using "load data infile"

Tags: php, mysql, csv, file-upload

The code below ignores the first five lines BUT I want to ignore last five lines of my CSV file

```
$query = <<<eof
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$fname'
 INTO TABLE rawdata_01
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
 LINES TERMINATED AT '\n'
 IGNORE 5 LINES
(SequenceNumber,CDRMajorVerision)
 eof;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mySQL doesn't have support for ignoring ending lines.

From [The MySQL 5.1 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

> The IGNORE number LINES option can be used to ignore lines at the
>   start of the file. For example, you can use IGNORE 1 LINES to skip
>   over an initial header line containing column names.

Instead, on a Linux system, you could go to a terminal window and use the command `head` to make a new file that omits the last 5 lines as follows:

`head --lines=-5 oldfile > newfile`

See: [man page for head](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head)

Your other alternatives, (e.g. for Windows), are loading the entire file and deleting the last 5 lines somehow, and writing a script to do what head does in your language of your choice.